How to enable Pytorch Dropout on Optimized for Mobile models
I have a model that uses dropout for MC prediction.  It works fine in Python on my desktop.  I'd like to execute the same algorithm on mobile platforms but the dropout does not seem to be applied.  I get the same result each MC iteration when evaluating the model on mobile.
First, I load the model in PyTorch and enable dropout as documented in other questions [1]
model.eval()
for m in model.modules():
    if m.__class__.__name__.startswith('Dropout'):            
        m.train()

return model

Next I optimize for mobile.  I've added the parameter to disable removing the dropout during the optimize method:
torchscript_model = torch.jit.script(model)
optimize_for_mobile(torchscript_model,
   optimization_blocklist={MobileOptimizerType.REMOVE_DROPOUT})
   ._save_for_lite_interpreter(ptlFile)

Lastly, in Android, I load the model then execute the MC iterations (simplified example)..
module = LiteModuleLoader.loadModuleFromAsset( this.getAssets(), "<ptlFile name>" );
<snip MC iterations>
float[] score = module.forward(IValue.from(inputTensor)).toTensor().getDataAsFloatArray();
</snip>

Each iteration I get the same score values.  Any suggestions how to achieve the same result on mobile as on the desktop?  If I remove the REMOVE_DROPOUT from the optimizer blocklist, the exported model is smaller in size.  So it seems as if the dropout layers are in the mobile model properly but they don't appear to be active during mobile evaluation.
Pytorch version 2.2.1 on Desktop.
pytorch_android_lite 1.13.1 on Android.
[1] Measuring uncertainty using MC Dropout on pytorch

There might be something in the inference code setting the model to eval. You can try write a custom dropout layer that doesn't change with the train/eval flag and see if that changes performance

Thanks Karl, that seems to be the trick.  Something sets the function sets the function back to eval during the optimization process so even though the layer exists in the model, it just makes the model larger but doesn't do anything.  This pointed me in the right direction to add my own layer that always evaluates dropout.

Even though the REMOVE_DROPOUT optimization block is working to leave those layers in the model, it appears that during optimizing for mobile, the dropout layers are being converted back to eval mode.  The fix was to swap out the dropout layers with a custom layer that does not consider the training parameter:
class AlwaysDropout(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dropout_prob):
        super(AlwaysDropout,self).__init__()
        self.dropout_prob = dropout_prob

    def forward(self,x):
        return torch.nn.functional.dropout2d(x,self.dropout_prob,True)

For my specific example, I'm using densenet from monai.  To swap out the dropout layers, I just replaced the factory function that creates them:
# overwrite the layer factory for monai Dropout
@monai.networks.layers.factories.Dropout.factory_function("dropout")
def dropout_factory(dim):
    return AlwaysDropout

